# How to get articles for last 2 days only in Python?

Tags: python, date, python-3.x, datetime

I write a program in Python3 to parse news. After the parsing every article has a date object (ex. (2016, 7, 9)).

What is the best way to save only articles that were published for the last 2 days only?

Comment: Which website are you using? Is it returning the whole data at a time? I don't think so? You can get one news article at a time and parse it to get the date and stop once you get the date later than 2 days.

Comment: @TrigonaMinima I parse multiple news websites using the newspaper library. It gives me information about every article like this: {
        'article_title': article.title,
        'article_date': article.publish_date,
        'article_author': article.authors,
        'article_text': article.text,
        'article_URL': article.url,
    } I need only articles for the last 2 days. I know I can get the current datetime and compare it. But what is the pythonic way to do that?

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is `timedelta`? Something like this - `datetime.datetime.utcnow().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=2)`

Comment: @Yonatan Kiron, timedelta really was the thing I was looking for, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said this was your answer:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.utcnow().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a list of articles:

```
import arrow

threshold = arrow.now().replace(days=-2)
filtered_articles = [a for a in articles if arrow.get(a['article_date')) > threshold]
```

Comment: This is a good way, but requires install of the arrow library. In my case, I had to use only the standard library. Anyway, thanks.